# how to interpret a generalised linear mixed model with binomial data

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, interpretation, binomial-distribution

I know there has been a similar question before but I'm struggling to use the answers there to help interpret my data. I'm new to statistics so am very keen for help! I have data where each row represents a habitat patch, and some of my columns include 'urban' (whether the patch is bordered by urban habitat or not), 'Pre_postdev' (whether the habitat came from a pre-development map or a post-development map), and 'project_ID' (I randomly sampled projects and then within those systematically sampled every habitat patch, hence why I'm using a mixed model). I have used the GLMM:

```r
glmm_urban <- glmer(urban ~ Pre_postdev + (1 | project_ID), 
                family = binomial(link = "logit"),
                data = size3)
```

In order to investigate the difference in proportion of habitat patches being bordered by urban habitat, between pre and post-development habitats. I've accounted for my sampling method with the random effect of project ID. I have two levels to my Pre_postdev variable, "pre" and "post" (which I reordered to be in that order), and "urban" is coded in binary where 1 is Yes and 0 is no.

However, I'm really struggling to interpret the output of my GLMM. Here it is:

```r
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace 
    Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
 Formula: urban ~ Pre_postdev + (1 | project_ID)
   Data: size3

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
   263.1    273.0   -128.6    257.1      198 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6526 -0.6816 -0.3952  0.7494  1.8038 

Random effects:
 Groups     Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 project_ID (Intercept) 1.415    1.19    
Number of obs: 201, groups:  project_ID, 12

Fixed effects:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    0.01086    0.41891   0.026    0.979
Pre_postdev.L  0.29207    0.24846   1.176    0.240

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
Pre_pstdv.L -0.140
```

1. Could you help explain how I should interpret this output? I don
2. How can I interpret 'log odds' into answering my research question (Are a higher proportion of patches bordered by urban habitats in post-development maps compared to pre-development maps?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering just based on the output presented, without any real understanding of the data or model diagnostics:

Also assuming the null hypothesis was that the Pre_postdev effect was not a significant contributor to the probability of a habitat patch being bordered by an urban area, and that the researchers intended to test this at a 0.05 type I error cutoff:

1. After accounting for the variance due to the Project_ID, there is insufficient evidence to conclude that the effect of Pre_postdev "post" is different from Pre_postdev "pre" in the probability of a habitat patch being bordered by an urban area. (p-value on Pre_postdev.L of 0.240 > 0.05)
2. The best way to understand how to interpret the coefficients is to write down the regression equation:

$$\textbf{ln}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \textbf{Pre_postdev} + \alpha_{\textbf{Project_ID}} + \epsilon$$

$$E(\alpha_{\textbf{Project_ID}}) = 0$$

$$E(\epsilon) = 0$$

$$\hat{p}|\textbf{Pre} = \frac{e^{\beta_0}}{1 + e^{\beta_0}}$$

$$\hat{p}|\textbf{Post} = \frac{e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1}}{1 + e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1}}$$

Difference in log-odds

$$\textbf{ln}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)_{\textbf{Post}} - \textbf{ln}\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)_{\textbf{Pre}} = \beta_1 = 0.29207$$

Ratio of odds

$$\frac{\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)_{\textbf{Post}}}{\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)_{\textbf{Pre}}} = e^{\beta_1} = 1.339$$

Comment: Thank you! I am quite confused on what the 'intercept' really is. When I make eg a coefficient plot, it again provides the difference between the intercept and Pre_postdev.L (which I think represents "post" development). Does intercept represent the other state, ie. the "pre" development state? If not, what does the estimate for Pre_postdev.L actually represent?

Comment: Yes.  In the construction of the model I used above, the intercept is the pre-development state.  If you were to add more covariates to the model, it can have other interpretations.  In languages like R, the intercept always represents the base state of any categorical variables.  If this answer was helpful, then please accept the answer.